# how to get a class reference to parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Is there any chance to assign to class reference the parameterized type eg.

```
    Class<Set>  c1= Set.class;   //OK
    Class<Set<Integer>> c2 = Set<Integer>.class; //Makes error
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `.class` literal with a class name, or invoking `getClass()` method on an object returns the `Class` instance, and for any class there is one and only one `Class` instance associated with it.

Same holds true for a generic type. A class `List<T>` has only a single class instance, which is `List.class`. There won't be different class types for different type parameters. This is analogous to how `C++` implements generics, where each generic type instantiation will have a separate `Class` instance. So in Java, you can't do `Set<Integer>.class`. Java doesn't allow that because it doesn't make sense, and might give wrong intentions about number of `Class` instances.

However, if you want a `Class<Set<Integer>>`, you can achieve that will a bit of type casting (which will be safe), as shown below:

```
Class<Set<Integer>> clazz = (Class<Set<Integer>>)(Class<?>) Set.class;
```

This will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Great thanks. I understand "type erasure" and  reflection but I did not know how to ged rid of annoying type safety warnings (eg. when dynamically invoked method is returning a parameterized type). Now I know:-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it this way, because the type-parameter information is gone at Runtime and the `.class` statement is actually evaluated then.

You can only do:

```
Set<Integer> someSet = ..
Class<?> c2 = someSet.class;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ClassName>>() {} Should work.
```

Example is giving below for exchange method Rest Template class exchange function

**Funcation Requirement**

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(URI url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) throws RestClientException
```

**Implementation**

```
restTemplate.exchange(new URI("Http://{host}:{port}/{url}"), HttpMethod.POST, customObject, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ResponseClassName>>() {});
```